# Total Number of pixels in an image

Tags: matlab

How to get the total number of pixel in an image (785x728) image. I have applied loops here and it is taking lot of time. Any easy way

```
for i=1:height
    for j=1:width
        for d=1:colorChannel
            value = double(rgbImage(i,j,d));
            display(i);
            totalSum = totalSum + value;
            display(totalSum);
        end

    end

end
```

Comment: Given a 785x728 3-channel image, what would the desired result be? Does `sum(rgbImage(:))` do what you want?

Comment: Yes it works.It comes out 143780359. My image size is 101 KB. When I looked into the imfinfo.FileSize then it returns 103222 to me. I want to reduce my image to 50 KB. How I will calculate how much to reduce from the total pixels comes and what is mean by 103222?

Comment: I don't understand what you want, sorry. Try to incorporate that into a well-phrased question so you can get more help

Comment: I want to reduce my image size which is 101 kb right now to 50 kb. The total sum from sum(rgbImage(:)) I got was 143780359. How I will achieve this.

Comment: `sum(rgbImage(:))` returns the sum of the pixel values. Reducing this number will just set your image darker (or color shifted). But the size will still be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of pixels is not equal to the sum of values in your image.

```
sumOfAllPixelValues = sum(double(rgbImage(:)));
numberOfPixels      = numel(rgbImage);
```

The size on disk of an image is `numberOfPixels*bytesPerPixel`, where `bytesPerPixel` depends on the bit depth of an image (`uint8` would be 8 bits=1 byte, for example.

To downsample the image by half, you can either reduce the bit depth (e.g. going from `uint16` to `uint8`, or you reduce the number of pixels by `sqrt(2)` in height and width, for example using `imresize`.