# How to decrease the size of an image by decreasing the pixels

Tags: matlab

I am trying to decrease the size of an image by reducing the pixel values present at width, height and colorChannel. I tried to make it 0 (means black) then value of the file size get increased.

Can anyone suggest how I can decrease the size wihout using imresize.

Comment: `imresize`.... ? Changin the value wont change the memory size....It takes the same memory to store the value 123212321 and the value 0.

Comment: You are using very ambiguous terms. Size, as in the number of rows and columns? The size of the object in memory in your matlab workspace? The file size on disk when you save it under a particular format? Decreasing the pixel intensities or their number? What is the "*pixel* value at width height and colorChannel"? This makes no sense.

Comment: This user already asked something similar with ambiguous terms which was closed and downvoted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202047/total-number-of-pixels-in-an-image

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the size of image by decrasing *quality* parameter (is equal to 75 in example below)

```javascript
sharp('input.jpg')
  .resize(300)
  .quality(75)
  .toFile('result.jpg', function(err, info) {
    if(err) console.error(err);
    console.log(info);
  });
```

Comment: the question has a matlab tag, your answer looks like javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

In matlab, `size` refers to the number of rows and columns of a matrix (or for dimensions higher than two, it's the length at each dimension.
e.g.

```
>> A = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5;0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1];
>> size(A)
ans =
     2     5
>> whos A
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  A         2x5                80  double
```

A takes 80 bytes in memory because it is an array of type `double`.
If A is to be used as an image, a way to reduce its memory footprint is to convert it to an unsigned 8-bit integer type, i.e. uint8:

```
>> A = im2uint8(A)
A =
   26   51   77  102  128
  153  179  204  230  255
>> whos A
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  A         2x5                10  uint8
```

But I have no idea why you'd care about the memory footprint on your matlab workspace.

It sounds to me like you *may* be trying to say is that you want to obtain a **file** which is of smaller size but without sacrificing resolution. But if that's the case, you need to specify what kind of output file we're talking about. If it's just a matlab `.mat` file, then the above is fine. If you're trying to convert to `.jpg` or `.png` or something, then it just depends on the kind of options you pass into your export function, which will decide the quality of compression etc.

Please clarify your question further if you want actually useful help.

Comment: That was not the question, but in order to lose as little information as possible, it might be useful to apply an histogram equalization before the im2uint8 function.